# Get all elements of class but group by siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a simple way to select all elements of a class, but group them by siblings?

For example:

```
<div class="main-div">
    <div class="get-this"></div>
    <div class="get-this"></div>
    <div class="get-this"></div>
    <div class="sub-div">
        <div class="get-this"></div>
        <div class="get-this"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="get-this"></div>
<div class="get-this"></div>
<div class="get-this"></div>
```

If I wanted to get all the elements of class `get-this` but wanted to loop through the elements that are siblings like in `main-div`, `sub-div` and outside of any div separately without assigning a separate class?  I can't think of a good way to do this without traversing the entire DOM.

Comment: what is the output you expect?

Comment: @epascarello I'm just trying to figure out how to loop through the siblings separately.  Like if I wanted to console.log the number of siblings in each group separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put their parent elements into a Set, then take the children of each parent.

```js
const parents = new Set(
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.get-this')]
    .map(div => div.parentElement)
);
const divs = [...parents].map(
  parent => [...parent.children].filter(child => child.matches('.get-this'))
);
console.log(divs);
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
    <div class="get-this"></div>
    <div class="get-this"></div>
    <div class="get-this"></div>
    <div class="sub-div">
        <div class="get-this"></div>
        <div class="get-this"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="get-this"></div>
<div class="get-this"></div>
<div class="get-this"></div>
```

Comment: nice. incase the asker is confused, a Set can only contain unique values, so when CertainPerformance gets all `get-this` elements, uses `map()` to get each of those element's parents, then puts them in a Set using `...` (expander), you end up with a list containing just the three different parent elements. They then use the `parents` Set, to find all children that match having the `get-this` class using `map()`, `filter()`, and `matches()`, placing them each into separate sub arrays, contained within an overarching array named `divs`.

Comment: That's a clever and clean implementation.  If there aren't any better responses by tomorrow I'll accept this answer.  Thank you!